# I have upgraded from 5.4.0-77 to 5.4.0.80 and now there is no prompt to enter a passphrase for the encrpted root volume

Tags: boot, luks

When trying to boot it stops with a message that it is waiting for the encrypted device when it previously prompted for a passphrase.

I can work around this by selecting the old kernel in the grub menu but can't find a fix to boot in the the most recent kernel.

Boot repair didn't work automatically, but I have uploaded a report here. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2GxZMbxxmg/

Any suggestions would be welcome!

thanks

David

Comment: Boot-Repair never works automagically, it has nothing to do with the reported problem and couldn't possibly be useful in such situation. What it is designed to do is check for and reinstall bootloaders, that's all. You have no problem with bootloaders, you have a problem with the current kernel version and you've found the workaround. I suggest you keep using it while updating your system regularly. Sooner than later a new kernel version will have it fixed.

Comment: can you add `sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.4.0-80-generic` to your question?